# Расширение/сужение типа при наследовании

Tags: java

только начинаю изучать Java
возник вопрос

```
public class Test10 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

           Dog parent = new Dog();
           Animal me = new Dog();
           me.setParent(parent);
           Dog myParent = me.getParent();   // ОШИБКА, несовместимость типов
    }
}     

class Animal{
  Animal parent;

  public void setParent(Animal parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
  }
  public Animal getParent() {
      return parent;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
   @Override
   public Dog getParent(){
      return (Dog) parent;
   }
}
```

почему возникает ошибка? переменная me хоть и типа Animal, но хранит ссылку на объект класса Dog, следовательно должен вызваться переопределенный метод getParent, который делает даункаст типа Animal до типа Dog и, как мне казалось, должен возвращать тип Dog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому-что могло быть и так:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
     @Override
     public Cat getParent() {
          return (Cat) parent;
     }
}

...
Cat parent = new Cat();
Animal me = new Dog();
me.setParent(parent);
Dog myParent = me.getParent(); //и что теперь делать?
```

Метод `Animal.getParent` не дает гарантии, [что вернется `Dog`](http://www.poorlydrawnlines.com/comic/deception/), на что и указывает компилятор. Компилятор в строго типизированном языке (Java) проверяет соответствие типа. То, что по логике там будет `Dog` компилятор проверить в общем случае не может, т.ч. он и не пытается.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! напряг извилины, вспомнил что когда-то читал про связывание, и сформулировал для себя ответ таким образом, поправьте где неправ: какого типа объект скрыт под переменной выясняется во время выполнения программы, соответственно до компиляции компилятор видит переменную Animal me и думает что мы (возможно!) вызовем метод класса Animal, который вернет объект класса Animal. Поэтому компилятор перестраховывается и требует явное приведение типа `Dog myParent=(Dog) me.getParent()`. А если метод вернет не объект класса Dog вовсе,то ошибка возникнет при выполнении,но код скомпилируется

Comment: @Den Пожалуйста! Вроде все правильно понимаете.